# Visual Studio Code - yellow triangle in the left of my code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Would you be kind to advise what is the purpose of a yellow triangle that appeared in the left of my code while I am working on my jupyter notebook cell? How can I get rid of it?

I tried to check if I can use a context menu when I click the right mouse button, but I can't find anything responsible for a yellow triangle.

[image: vscode printscreen]

Comment: Current Line, perhaps?

Comment: It seems it's not a current line because when I am editing another jupyter notebook cell in my vs code there is no yellow triangle. It appeared only in one cell.

Comment: That is the icon to denote your current line when you are debugging - if you aren't debugging and you are seeing this, its possibly a visual bug, perhaps left over from a previous debug session.  Does reloading VS Code remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the debug icon for the current stack frame break-point. It shows you where the debugger has paused execution. If you're seeing that, either it's a bug, or you're in the middle of a debug session. If you want to end the debug session, (a non-notebook one) go to the debug toolbar and click the stop button, or run the `Debug: Stop` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette), or use the keybinding for that command (defaults to <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd>). For a notebook, you'd press the stop button that replaces the play button when debugging a cell. But here it looks like a bug because the play button is showing.

Comment: Your knowledge is awsome. Thanks all of you.